# images not appearing in canvas on chrome in iOS7

Tags: html, canvas, ios7, haxe, openfl

I'm using haxe and openfl to create an html5 application. I tested the app in multiple browsers and devices, all work fine except in Chrome on iOS 7 only. The images used are not appearing seemingly randomly. Every time I re load different images appear and others disappear with exception to a couple that are always there. Here is what I tried:

I tried setting the z-index on the canvas that is used for one of the missing images, as well as a bigger width and height. 
I know that the images are being loaded, I used Charles to take a look. There are no errors in the console log and changing the time and place where the images are being added to the display list in haxe changes nothing.
I swapped out one of the images that are always there for an image that is never there and it still didn't load.
The file names had a couple dashes and spaces in them so I changed that as well with no effect.

It's a very strange problem that I can't seem to diagnose. nor can I really find anyone with a similar problem.

The main issue is the fact that I can't see what haxe is building that might be causing this issue.

Comment: Been having the same issue with plain javascript. Apple forcing iOS browsers to use their iOS-Webkit rendering engine but forbidding them from using their Nitro javascript engine is just a recipe for disaster. It's no secret that they are trying to discourage webapps...but this is just mean.

Comment: could you post some sample code which you tested and is showing the same behaviour? (or actual code)

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without code samples. My advise is to look at what's different about the pictures that stay versus the ones that don't, both in how you're coding and the pictures themselves. I've had problems with images displaying correctly on ios only to find the problem was embedded somewhere in the metadata of an image. Hope this helps.